# Spring Data REST Events for Entity Association updates

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Are there any spring data rest event handlers available for when a new entity association is created ? I.e. PUT a to an association resource url.

My entity class with the relationship is:

```
public class Group{
  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "user_groups",
           joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id"),
           inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  )
  private List<User> users;
}
```

I have tried a PUT to /groups/[id]/users, and this will attach the user to the group successfully, but I can not find an event handler that can be used after this type of event.

I have also tried updating with a PUT to /groups/[id]/users using a links object, which also attaches the object successfully:

```
{"_links":
  {"users": 
    {"href" : "http://localhost:8084/users/1"} 
  }
}
```

My two attempted event handlers are:

```
@HandleAfterLinkSave
public void handleGroupUpdate(Group g, User u){
    log.debug("User "+u.getUsername() +"added to group "+g.getName());
}

@HandleAfterLinkSave
public void handleGroupUpdateGen(Object g, Object u){
    log.debug("User "+u.toString() +"added to group "+g.toString());
}
```

Events: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events

Association resources: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource

Comment: Did you get this working ? I am able to get the HandleBeforeLinkSaveand HandleAfterLinkSave event working ... I have put using the following command -------------    curl -v -X PUT -H "Content-Type: text/uri-list" -d "http://localhost:8080/users/1" http://localhost:
8080/userGroups/1/users

Comment: I still have not been able to get this working. Can you post the relationship between your users and groups?

Answer (score 2):

The proper parameters for the text/uri-list would be

```
public void handleGroupUpdate(Group g, List<User> u)
```

This aligns with the users field definition inside of the Group class.

Comment: Thank you for this correct answer.  The signature of your handle method must include the list of users as a second parameter.  The spring docs do not mention that.

Comment: A small addition: The supplied list of properties contains ALL of the properties, not only the ones which were just added.

Comment: What if the entity has links to multiple entities? How would that work? let's say Group g has links to 2 lists of users. This is possible in Mongo, to have more than one dbref field.